# How to set height and width in DP from PX

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing android application that will work on wide range on android mobile phones (not tablets).
Now designer give me designed PSD files and ask me to set the size of elements according to it.

Now in these files for example an element is having height and width of 90px, how many DP should I set it on my android XML layout file?

More I am creating a single layout for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xdpi. 
I tried http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/ to calculate the same,

but if I choose 90PX, it shows different DP size for ld, md, hd and xd. How can I set DP size in a single layout file that can run on variety of devices?

Please advice,
Regards,
Bhavin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but if I choose 90PX, it shows different DP size for ld, md, hd and
>   xd. How can I set DP size in a single layout file that can run on
>   variety of devices?

=> For your information, DP stands for Density Independent Pixels and that's where the difference between PX and DP comes into the picture.

So if you really want to provide compatibility to all the resolutions/density then you would have to declare dp values in different `dimens.xml` under different values directory.

The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen and 1.5 physical pixel on 240 dpi screen. This can be calculated using `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`.

**Ratio for declaring density values is: xhdpi: 2.0, hdpi: 1.5, mdpi: 1.0 (baseline), ldpi: 0.75**

### Standard practice:

Standard practice is to declare dp values (with same name in all values directory) in different dimens.xml under different values directory and reference the particular dimension value wherever required. Based on the density value, Android system will decide itself to use particular density value (I mean dp value to be taken from particular `dimens.xml` file).

**For example:**

```
values/
    dimens.xml
values-land/
    dimens.xml
values-xlarge-land
    dimens.xml
values-large
    dimens.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the dp to pix from following link.

http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/

(OR)

you can calculate the pixels based on device density.
LDPI - 0.75
MDPI - 1.0
HDPI - 1.5
XHDPI- 2.0

Answer (score 2):

you can keep single layout.xml and create multiple values directory(with different dimension values) for varying devices.

Answer (score 1):

One way is you create single layout.xml and multiple values directory for varying devices.

Other way is DP as  Dyou know is Density Independent Pixels, so to use **DP calculate the DP value of pixel base on one screen resolution HDPI,XHPDI,LDPI,MDPI etc recommended (HDPI)**.As you have One psd ask your UI designer for which screen type is that based on that calculate the DP help of angrytools and use That DP in your layout.As **Dp is also not fully accurate** on various device need some adjustment some time use **Value directories at that time**.

Thanks.